# Why is my WebView's WebViewClient not being called?

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I have a WebView, and after setting up a custom WebViewClient with WebView.setWebViewClient, the WebViewClient methods do not seem to be called. In particular I'm overriding onLoadResource and onReceivedError. However, neither of these are called after calling WebView.loadUrl();

Here's the code in question: https://gist.github.com/9673b619e019038848a0

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are looking for the correct log message and that your device is outputting logging properly? I essentially copied your code into a clean project and it appears to work perfectly. Glancing at the documentation it looks like you are following everything properly.

I am using the webview as the content view, that is the only significant difference I see.

For reference here is my test activity:

```
package com.testing.androidtest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String APP_TAG = "MYAPP";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
                Log.d(APP_TAG, consoleMessage.message());
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.e(APP_TAG, "Error in WebView: " + failingUrl + "; " + description);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "loading resource: " + url);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");

        setContentView(webView);
    }

}
```